# inspec run a single control as sudo

Tags: chef-infra, inspec

I am using inspec to verify some AMIs that I am building, and in the main I want the controls in the profile to run as a normal user so I can test as a standard user would see things.

However there area couple of controls that I want to run as root (sudo) to check things like services.

I know I can pass --sudo to the exec command but that runs the whole profile as sudo.  Is it possible to elevate a single control? (you would use become in Ansible).
Or do I need to write two profiles and execute them independantly?

Answer (score 1):

hmm, if its just a single control couldn't you just use `su -l USERNAME -c COMMAND` and capture the output? Might not be ideal to use the command resource, but this would give you access to the users' environment. i.e.:

```
root@machine:~# su -l ubuntu -c env
```

Comment: oops, meant to put that in inspec format:
`describe command( 'su -l ubuntu -c env') do`

Comment: Seems like this is the only way to go :/ Shame they dont just add a option to run as different user.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below method to run sudo commands remotely via chef inspec:

```
history_file = ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -tt #{input('host')} sudo find / -name '.mysql_history'.strip 

file_check = ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -tt #{input('host')} sudo ls -l #{history_file}.strip
```